# Jenkins Unexpectedly Changes Workspace Directory - Why?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, cicd

I've set up a Jenkins pipeline configured as a "Pipeline project" with the following configuration:

```kotlin
pipeline {
  options {
    disableConcurrentBuilds()
  } 
  agent any
  environment {
    REGION = 'us-east-1'
    ENV = "${params.ENVIRONMENT}"
    JENKINS_NODE="jenkins-${ENV}"
    def BUILDVERSION = sh(script: "echo `date +%Y%m%d%H%M`", returnStdout: true).trim()
  }   
  stages {
    stage('Creating and sharing snapshot from prod') {
      steps {
        node("jenkins-prod") {
          dir("/home/centos/workspace/DBClusterMigration") {
            sh '''
              aws rds create-db-cluster-snapshot --db-cluster-snapshot-identifier prod-${BUILDVERSION} --db-cluster-identifier prod --region ${REGION}
              aws rds copy-db-cluster-snapshot --source-db-cluster-snapshot-identifier prod-${BUILDVERSION} --target-db-cluster-snapshot-identifier reencrypted-prod-${BUILDVERSION} --kms-key-id b21e3752-3797-4604-9136-b0fc6d40cd3b --region ${REGION}
              aws rds modify-db-cluster-snapshot-attribute --db-cluster-snapshot-identifier reencrypted-prod-${BUILDVERSION} --attribute-name restore --values-to-add "782918959274" "953441081555" "451870394779" --region ${REGION}
            '''
          }
        }  
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

Despite explicitly setting the working directory using the dir("/home/centos/workspace/DBClusterMigration") command, Jenkins keeps altering its working directory to a newly created workspace. This new workspace doesn't seem to have the latest changes from git. For instance:

```scss
Running on jenkins-prod in /home/centos/workspace/DBClusterMigration@2
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ aws rds create-db-cluster-snapshot --db-cluster-snapshot-identifier 202310250709 --db-cluster-identifier prod --region us-east-1
    
An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the CreateDBClusterSnapshot operation: Invalid cluster snapshot identifier:  202310250709
```

I even explicitly set current dir with dir("/home/centos/workspace/DBClusterMigration") command but it didn't work at all.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. In the console log you posted, it says it's running in the directory you specified.

Comment: @CAustin
Uhm, no, sir. In the stage section I have `"/home/centos/workspace/DBClusterMigration"` directory and in the log it says `"/home/centos/workspace/DBClusterMigration@2"`. Small difference, but crucial.

Answer (score 0):

This occurrence when Jenkins appends @2, @3, etc., to the workspace directory is usually due to concurrent builds on the same pipeline, using the same agent.

However, in your case, you have applied `disableConcurrentBuilds()` in the  `options` block of the pipeline.

In this case the most likely cause, is either:

- The job is part of a multi-branch pipeline and Jenkins may still use a separate workspace if it believes the primary workspace is being used by another build (within the multi branch) or is otherwise unavailable
- The agent declared in the pipeline is `agent any`, so it could be that the same node is being used by multiple jobs / multibranch pipeline for the same workspace

### Remediation

- Use a dedicated node for your pipeline
- Clear down the workspace after every build has completed, mitigating the risk of it already existing on the node called, when starting a new pipeline

See example below:

```kotlin
pipeline {
  options {
    disableConcurrentBuilds()
  } 
  agent {
    docker {
      image 'dockernode:latest'
      alwaysPull true
    }
  }
  environment {
    REGION = 'us-east-1'
    ENV = "${params.ENVIRONMENT}"
    JENKINS_NODE="jenkins-${ENV}"
    def BUILDVERSION = sh(script: "echo `date +%Y%m%d%H%M`", returnStdout: true).trim()
  }   
  stages {
    stage('Creating and sharing snapshot from prod') {
      steps {
        node("jenkins-prod") {
          dir("/home/centos/workspace/DBClusterMigration") {
            sh '''
              aws rds create-db-cluster-snapshot --db-cluster-snapshot-identifier prod-${BUILDVERSION} --db-cluster-identifier prod --region ${REGION}
              aws rds copy-db-cluster-snapshot --source-db-cluster-snapshot-identifier prod-${BUILDVERSION} --target-db-cluster-snapshot-identifier reencrypted-prod-${BUILDVERSION} --kms-key-id b21e3752-3797-4604-9136-b0fc6d40cd3b --region ${REGION}
              aws rds modify-db-cluster-snapshot-attribute --db-cluster-snapshot-identifier reencrypted-prod-${BUILDVERSION} --attribute-name restore --values-to-add "782918959274" "953441081555" "451870394779" --region ${REGION}
            '''
          }
        }  
      }
    }
  }
  post {
    always {
      cleanWs()
    }
  }
}
```